# Godaddy automatic renewals (Powershell & alternatives)

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

how are you?
My orgazation is transitioning to using GoDaddy certificates, and I'm exploring if there's an established automated process to download and apply renewed certificates from GoDaddy to our Windows or Linux servers

I've been researching this, but so far, I haven't come across any practical solutions. Could someone provide guidance or assistance in this matter

Can somebody help me out?